# Why HBase Delete Reverts Back to Previous Value instead of Totally Deleting it

Tags: hbase

Let's say I have a column named `signup_date` with a value `2019-09-09`. Then I will update this column to `2019-11-11`. So `signup_date` is now `2019-11-11`.

After that, if I delete the `signup_date` column, I expect it to be gone in the Hbase BUT, it remains there and it's reverted back to `2019-09-09`.

Is this a bug in hbase where deleted columns are reverted back to previous values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved already http://apache-hbase.679495.n3.nabble.com/Why-HBase-Delete-Reverts-Back-to-Previous-Value-instead-of-Totally-Deleting-it-td4103693.html

Basically the issue was that we are using addColumn when it should have been addColumns in our hbase delete. The addColumn reverts back to the previous version (thus the value is reverted back to previous value when deleted) while addColumns deletes all existing version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify VERSIONS and MIN_VERSIONS for the column family in your table? Suppose, you specified MIN_VERSIONS as 3, then each time when you overwrite the existing data it will be stored as another version. So, basically, when you deleted the column it just deleted the latest version and when you get the value for that it will you the previous version. This is actually the expected behavior.

You can change the properties by altering the column family in your table.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of HBase doesn't delete or overwrite cells immediately.
When you delete a cell, it gets marked with a tombstone and gets filters out by a scanner during scanning a table.

But when you just override an old version, it doesn't get marked in any way. All cells older that `MAX_VERSION_CONFIGURED_IN_THE_TABLE` will be deleted during major compaction. Until then during a table scanning you have max versions per column based on:
`min(MAX_VERSION_CONFIGURED_IN_THE_TABLE, MAX_VERSION_CONFIGURED_IN_THE_SCANER)`

But if you delete a new cell before major compaction is performed newest from overwritten versions will pop out.